# insert data into table by sql in rails3

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm stuck in this scenario:

I've a `table(it is not a model)` and want to insert data in it via `Rails`.

For example:

```
Table name:  Last updates
fields:  another_table_id:integer, last_time:datetime
```

I want to insert data into this?

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer,

```
connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SQL query")
```

we can perform any query in Rails.